# Replace .(dot) inside number Java between two elements

Tags: java

I have this String:

```
String str = "<p>23.5</p>";
```

And i want to replace the dot for comma only inside

elements. The output i need is:

```
<p>23,5</p>
```

I cant figure it out, i have this:

```
str = str.replaceAll("(?<=<p>)\\.(?=</p>)", ",");
```

But it doesnt work. I need to replace dot only in elements with particular tag (is an xml in a String), in this case

.

Thank you

Comment: Your regex looks massively more complicated than your example string. Can the `<p>`-tags contain attributes or is it always `<p>value</p>`?

Comment: what about `str.replaceAll("\\.", ",");`?

Comment: You forgot to escape the `/` in `</p>`.

Comment: I cant replace all, becouse its a long String that have names with .(dots) that i have to mantain. I only need to replace . for , in two tags. In this example is just one <p></p>, but i have 3 with different names with decimal values

Comment: @Smutje Its always a decimal value with .(dot), and i need to change it to ,(comma). This example is simple, but its a long XML in String. 
Si i want to replace dot for comma in few tags that i have.

Comment: _its a long String that have names with .(dots)_ - does the string has numerical characters, not the ones within html tags, with dot in between them?

Comment: @Yousaf Yes, but i need to replace all numeric values that have dots for commas, maybe this is a easier approach for someone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use capturing groups + escape the `/`:

```
str = str.replaceAll("(?<=<p>)(\\d*)\\.(\\d+)(?=<\\/p>)", "$1,$2");
```

If you want to replace dot in all numbers, you may just as well use

```
str = str.replaceAll("(\\d*)\\.(\\d+)", "$1,$2");
```

Comment: Beautiful, thank you man. Spasibo))). I think i over complicated myself, when the easier approach was just replace all numbers that have dots in my case.

Thank you again

Comment: @AlexDanilov You're welcome) I've made a mistake - it allows for points without any numbers around it, so replaces all the points. Do you have any numbers like ".5" or "1."?

Comment: Actually yes i have, just notice it actually. I have one part r2.randomletters

Answer (score 1):

Following regex will match the dot character that is between numerical characters

```
(?<=\d)\.(?=\d)
```

**Regex Explanation:**

- `\d` - match any digit between 0-9
- `(?<=\d)\.` - positive look-behind to match any `.` character that has a digit just before it
- `\.(?=\d)` - positive look-ahead to match any `.` character that has a digit just after it

**Demo:**

https://regex101.com/r/WMEjPl/1

**Java Code Example:**

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
   String regex = "(?<=\\d)\\.(?=\\d)";
  
   String str = "<p>23.5</p>";
   String str2 = "Mr. John <p>23.5</p> Hello";
   String str3 = "Mr. John <p>23.5</p> Hello 12.2324";

   System.out.println(str.replaceAll(regex, ","));   // <p>23,5</p>
   System.out.println(str2.replaceAll(regex, ","));  // Mr. John <p>23,5</p> Hello
   System.out.println(str3.replaceAll(regex, ","));  // Mr. John <p>23,5</p> Hello 12,2324
}
```